# Laptop HDD failure imminent?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I have an HP Compaq 615 laptop with an 160 GB 7200 rpm HDD. Hasn't been dropped or shaken, in fact it almost always stayed on my desk. I've treated it as nice as I could.

The other day, however, my OS froze and I could hear a repeated clink-clink-clink coming from the HDD zone of the laptop. I had to switch off hardware-ly the laptop and re-start it.

It worked very well after, including now. However I backed up immediately the core data on my USB drive and ordered an external USB HDD for periodic backups.

Will it die soon or it was just a "blip"?

L.E.: I checked both partitions fully, using checkdisk/scandisk including for bad sectors and **nothing** bad appeared..

Comment: What OS? Clicks do tend to indicate dodgy drives. Check bad sectors and smart attributes as per Mark's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is use a utility like [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/) to check the drive.  HD Tune uses the [S.M.A.R.T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) protocol which is intended to warn you of an impending drive failure.

Comment: Pay special attention to the highlighted entries; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes

Answer (score 0):

Use a disk utility (Palimpsest under Ubuntu Live for example) that will display the SMART drive information. It should give you some insight into what happened.